# Why is "/game/owner_id/1234" better than "/game?owner_id=1234" when building a REST endpoint?

Tags: rest

Question says it all.  I see the former done fairly often but it seems to me like it makes more work for the front-end and back-end developer than just using standard HTTP query parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about "better", but one advantage it has is *it shows a hierarchy* whereas the form with just the query parameter does not:

Looking at the resource indicates quickly that it relates to "a particular [game] owner". Although, perhaps `/games/owner/XYZ` is more appropriate than `/games/owner_id/XYZ` ..

Also, I think it's "prettier" to look at.

I do not agree with the proposed it "makes more work" argument, because it's *still* just a URI and there is *still* some defined API. REST-ful frameworks generally support URL mapping as part of the standard package.

Comment: I can see how it showing a hierarchy would be beneficial but, no offense, being prettier is not a good enough reason to reinvent the wheel.  The reason I think it is more work is because the developer has to write code to parse along the path but most web servers and app servers have some facility for accessing query parameters built into them.  e.g. PHP's $_GET array.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon It was in quotes, just like "better". It is not "re-inventing the wheel", however. A URI is a URI.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon Well, that's problem #1: Not using an appropriate framework/library for the task. These things exist. I wouldn't generate XML without one; why would I do REST-ful mappings without one?